# Flexbox div will not take full available height when nested in div

Tags: html, angularjs, css, flexbox

How can I get the Chart div in the following fiddle to flex in vertical size to use the available height? I know this question has been asked before but I have tried following similar questions which were commonly solved by adding "height: 100%;" to the parent containers, but this does not seem to be helping here and I think I must be making a mistake elsewhere with the flex CSS.

I have attempted to make the fiddle represent the nested structure of our app, as we have several Angular controllers and directives involved in the view.

This is needed in Chrome (although it is also not working in Firefox either).

https://fiddle.jshell.net/fb7yLs5c/

You can see at the bottom of my fiddle that I commented out another Chart which lies outside of the 2 parent divs of the broken one. This one will indeed flex it's height to the full vertical space, but the one inside the two Angular-based divs will not.

The idea is that the Chart has a minimum height ("flex-basis: 400px;") but if the window is made taller than that, it should expand to fill all available vertical height.

Answer (score 0):

flex wrapper has no height, when you set it to 100% the chart will expand, you will get a scroll because the other elements are not taken into consideration. here's what to do
set flexwrapper to 100% height
put all the elements except your chart in a div with position relative and height to about 30%
set the height of your chart to 70%
play with the heights to meet your design goals

Comment: OK I've quickly tried that: https://fiddle.jshell.net/2183zv2k/


Like you said, the chart starts resizing once flexWrapper height is set to 100%, but we gain a scroll for the size of the other elements. I added the relative 30% div but now I get a resizing empty area above the chart. Is this what you meant? We don't need the height of the controls to scale any higher than they are to fill this space, we would only like the chart to take up the available space.

Comment: add the other elements inside the empty area

Answer (score 0):

You need to make container's parent to a `flex` element. And set `flex-direction:column`  Then your code will work as you expected it to be.

```css
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
.app {
  height:100%;
}

.authorised-pane {
  height: 100%;
}

#flexWrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    min-height: 100%; /*height or min-height both work */
}

.version {
    padding:5px;
    color: #777777;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.panel-selection-style {
    background-color: green;
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: 32px;
}

.navButton {
  padding: 5px;
}

.instrumentControls {
    display: flex;
    background-color: orange;
    flex-basis: 32px;
}

.chartControls {
    display: flex;
    background-color: blue;
    flex-basis: 32px;
}

#chart {
    background-color: yellow;
    flex:50;
    display: flex;
    flex-basis:400px;
    height: 100%;
}
/*additional css*/
    .panelCtrl{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   flex: 1 1 auto;
    }
   .graphCtrl {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
     }
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" style="height:100%;">
    <div class="authorised-pane">
        <div ng-controller="PanelCtrl" style="height:100%;">
            <div id="flexWrapper">
                <span class="version">Version</span>
                <span class="panel-selection-style">
                <!-- Buttons for panel selection, ie. choose content -->
                  <button class="navButton">
                    Button 1
                  </button>
                  <button class="navButton">
                    Button 2
                  </button>
                  <button class="navButton">
                    Button 3
                  </button>
                  <button class="navButton">
                    Button 4
                  </button>
                  <button class="navButton">
                    Button 5
                  </button>
                </span>

                <div class="panelCtrl" ng-show="panelCtrl.tabs.graph" style="height:100%;">
                    <div class="graphCtrl" ng-controller="GraphCtrl" ng-include="graph.html" style="height:100%;">

                        <!--now inside ng-included graph.html-->
                        <span class="instrumentControls">
                      <button class="navButton">
                        Instrument Control 1
                      </button>
                      <button class="navButton">
                        Instrument Control 2
                      </button>

                            <!--contents of a replay toolbar directive-->
                      <span>
                      <button></button>
                      <button></button>
                      </span>
                      <span>
                      <button>></button>
                      <button>>></button>
                      </span>

                            <!--End of instrument controls -->
                    </span>

                        <!-- contents of chart directive -->
                        <div class="chartControls">
                            <button class="navButton">
                                ToB
                            </button>
                            <button class="navButton">
                                DoB
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <div id="chart">
                            Chart should fill full height
                        </div>
                        
                      </span>

                    <!-- GraphCtrl end -->
                    </div>
                    
                <!-- ngShow end -->
                </div>

<!--                 <div id="chart" style="background-color: red;">
                    Commented out Chart here DOES fill full height
                </div> -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Here is a fiddle of the above example https://fiddle.jshell.net/azs06/zL3tddyf/1/

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like this will only flex the height up to the value of the flex-basis (400px) and then it will not fill the rest of the space

Comment: Hey, Sorry it didn't worked, I updated my code, now it should stretch to full height, here is a jsbin of the code https://jsbin.com/dejesef/edit?html,css,output